# 500 error when uploading an image from iOS to IIS post webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis, iis-8, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to upload a file to an IIS 8 server from my .NET website. When I upload it **from the desktop, everything works fine** and the webservice returns success. When I try to upload the image through my iPhone iOS, I gt a 500 internal server error. Is there any way to detect the exact internal exception from the log, because I could'nt find anything specific, just a 500 for the webservice all.I have the option to put console.log() and get information from the client side, but it doesn't help me to detect the problem. I can't debug it as usually because I browse the site through a mobile phone.

Comment: you can enable detailed error from IIS >> Error pages >> Edit this feature >> Select radio button "detailed error". This should show detailed error instead of only 500..

Comment: I turned it on, In the logs I still see 500, nothing more specific

Answer (score 1):

Turn on **[Failed Request Tracing](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis)** in IIS, you can use the GUI or PowerShell like this:

```
 $siteName = "name of your web site"

 Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpTracing

 Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name=`'$siteName`']/traceFailedRequestsLogging" -name "enabled" -value "True"

 Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/$siteName"  -filter "system.webServer/tracing/traceFailedRequests" -name "." -value @{path='*'}
 Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/$siteName"  -filter "system.webServer/tracing/traceFailedRequests/add[@path='*']/traceAreas" -name "." -value @{provider='ASPNET';areas='Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices';verbosity='Verbose'}
 Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/$siteName"  -filter "system.webServer/tracing/traceFailedRequests/add[@path='*']/failureDefinitions" -name "statusCodes" -value "500"
 Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/$siteName"  -filter "system.webServer/tracing/traceFailedRequests/add[@path='*']/traceAreas" -name "." -value @{provider='WWW Server';areas='Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,WebSocket';verbosity='Verbose'}
```

after that run your failing requests and check the log files under `C:\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles\`

it is easier to copy the files to your workstation and open them in IE